# Sending image via ajax to multer

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ajax, multer

I'm using Multer to upload an image file into my node server, and it always comes back to giving me undefined for using ajax to send the image.

Ajax :

```
image = $("#input-file-img").val()
                const data = new FormData();
                 data.append("image", image);
                 $.ajax({
                    url: '/uploadfile/' + userName,
                    method: 'POST',
                    async: false,
                    processData: false ,
                    contentType: false,
                    data: data
                })
```

Upload.js

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, 'uploads')
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, file.originalname)
  }
})
var upload = multer({ storage: storage })

router.post('/uploadfile/:userName', upload.single('image'), async (req, res, next) => {
  let user = await User.findOne({ userName: req.params.userName })
  let file = req.file
  let fileName = file.filename
  let path = variables.kepler + 'uploads/' + fileName
  user.image = path
  await user.save()
  if (!path) {
    const error = new Error('Please upload a file ...')
    error.httpStatusCode = 400
    return next(error)
  }

  if (path) {
    return res.status(200).send({
      status: '200',
      message: 'Operation completed successfully ...',
      data: user,
      path
    })
  }
})
```

I checked the image value with console and it shows  C:\fakepath\Capture d’écran de 2019-09-19 11-33-59.png'

Would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!!!

getting value by

```
image = $("#input-file-img").val()
```

that means I was sending a type String as a file

so I had to change it to

```
image = $('#input-file-img')[0].files[0]
```

and everything works really well

Answer (score 0):

I think your server side code is fine, if I modify the client side code as below, everything works nicely, we end up with images in the /uploads folder:

```
function base64toBlob(base64, mimeType) {
    const bytes = atob(base64.split(',')[1]);
    const arrayBuffer = new ArrayBuffer(bytes.length);
    const uintArray = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
    for (let i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
        uintArray[i] = bytes.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    return new Blob([ arrayBuffer ], { type: mimeType });
}

function submitForm() {         
    const imgRegEx = /^data:(image\/(gif|png|jpg|jpeg))/;
    const imageData = $('#input-file-img').attr('src');
    const mimeType = imgRegEx.exec(imageData)[1];
    const blob = base64toBlob(imageData, mimeType);

    const fileExt = mimeType.replace("image/", "");
    const fileName = "test-image." + fileExt; // Change as appropriate..

    const data = new FormData();
    data.append("image", blob, fileName);

    $.ajax({
        url: '/uploadfile/' + userName,
        method: 'POST',
        async: false,
        processData: false ,
        contentType: false,
        data: data
    })
}
```